# TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNPermissionsModule' could not be found., when using react-native-permissions and expo

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler, react-native-permissions

I have a React Native app built using Expo and I am trying to configure permissions using [`react-native-permissions` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions). To test the app I am using [Expo Go](https://expo.dev/client) on my iPhone.

When running my react native app on Expo Go, I get the following errors:

```
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNPermissionsModule' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary., js engine: hermes
    
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

I have tried removing the following code: Afterwards the app works as normal and the error messages doesn't appear. So it is likely that it is being caused by the [`react-native-permissions` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions).

```js
useEffect(() => {

        check(PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE)
            .then((result) => {
                if( result === RESULTS.GRANTED || result === RESULTS.LIMITED){
                    setLocationPermission(true);
                }
                else{
                    setLocationPermission(false);
                }
            })

        console.log(locationPermission);

    }, []);
```

But I still get the error if I remove that code and still import the library:

```js
import {check, PERMISSIONS, RESULTS} from 'react-native-permissions';
```

I have found similar questions posted, but none of them answer my question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have found a solution, for anyone else who has a similar issue.

If you are using Expo to build your react native app, then it is better to use [`expo-location`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/) library instead. Expo also offer other libraries for helping you access other permissions.

`expo-location` also allows you to access the location information as well as request permission.

I'm not sure why I was getting the error with the previous library (possibly because it was incompatible with Expo) but this solution worked for me.

Comment: Same issue I am facing. But I am not using expo Can you please suggest something?